# Ensuring that a variadic template contains no duplicates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I guess my whole problem is well described in the title. I am trying to create a variadic class template (in C++11, C++14 or C++1z).

```
template<typename ...Types> struct MyVariadicTemplate {};
```

and make sure that the list of types in any instantiation of `MyVariadicTemplate` is injective, so if I, for instance, call the following piece of code:

```
MyVariadicTemplate<int, double, int> x;
```

it won't compile (I'd be happy to do that somehow using `static_assert`).

I would appreciate a hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be written with the help of two metafunctions.

First, `IsContained` checks whether a type appears in a type list.

```
template <typename T, typename... List>
struct IsContained;

template <typename T, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct IsContained<T, Head, Tail...>
{
    enum { value = std::is_same<T, Head>::value || IsContained<T, Tail...>::value };
};

template <typename T>
struct IsContained<T>
{
    enum { value = false };
};
```

Second, `IsUnique` checks whether a type list contains no duplicates. It uses `IsContained` to check all element combinations.

```
template <typename... List>
struct IsUnique;

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct IsUnique<Head, Tail...>
{
    enum { value = !IsContained<Head, Tail...>::value && IsUnique<Tail...>::value };
};

template <>
struct IsUnique<>
{
    enum { value = true };
};
```

With these tools, the static assertion is then very simple:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct NoDuplicates
{
    static_assert(IsUnique<Ts...>::value, "No duplicate types allowed");
};
```

Comment: Wow, that's clever. I have just seen the factorial example, but it didn't cross my mind to apply that. It comes useful in my further work too, because I would have needed IsContained anyway. Thank you

Comment: I love the `enum { value = ... }` in lieu of `static constexpr auto value = ...`

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to C++1z fold expressions, you can simplify @TheOperator's answer by doing the following for `IsContained`:

```
template <typename T, typename... List>
struct IsContained;

template <typename T, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct IsContained<T, Head, Tail...>
{
    enum { value = std::is_same<T, Head>::value || (IsContained<T, Tail>::value && ... && true) };
};

template <typename T>
struct IsContained<T>
{
    enum { value = false };
};
```

The difference is that with the fold expression there is a larger chance of re-use of the class instantiations.  If you are using a lot of parameters or have many repeat comparisons, this *might* have a faster compilation time. As always, test it out yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity though - is it necessary to add ( && true) at the end of the fold expression? Here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold it's mentioned that the fold && evaluates to true given an empty pack.

Comment: @Jytug in recent standardization meetings they removed all of the defaults for unary folds and made unary folds with an empty pack ill formed (see P0160R0). That's why I did the binary fold (with the && true)

Comment: (IsContained<T, Tail>::value && ... && true) this is incorrect!
Instead use (IsContained<T, Tail>::value || ... || false)  because fold expression result should be true in case if any IsContained<T, Tail>::value is true.

Answer (score -1):

With c++17 this is pretty easy.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct are_distinct: std::conjunction<
    std::negation<std::is_same<T, Ts>>...,
    are_distinct<Ts...>
>{};

template <typename T>
struct are_distinct<T>: std::true_type{};
```

The algorithm is the same as the one illustrated by [Jkor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34123002/566849) and [TheOperator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34122593/566849), but expressed much more concisely.

Then, coming to your specific question, you'd use it this way:

```
template<typename ...Types> 
struct MyVariadicTemplate {
    static_assert(are_distinct<Types...>::value, "Types must be distinct");

    /* rest of the code */
};
```

However, given this is O(n²), I wonder if there's a way to make it less algorithmically complex? [Boost::mpl's unique<> is O(n)](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/unique.html), but I can't get my head around the algo it uses.